# django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1:3307' (61)")

Tags: mysql, django, database, heroku

I got this error in the process of deploying my django app to heroku and here is the solution I figured :

Change the DATABASE PORT to : '3306'
and if you're still getting the error keep the port to '3307' and run your database server from Xampp.

Comment: Not sure how you got here or why. 3306 is the default outbound connection port for mysql. I guess you had the port wrong, but where is your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'db_demo',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '12345',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '3306'
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.